# Enable button when something was changed in the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created MVC5 application with table and have create page  with the following code which include text boxes ,check boxes and drop down list,
the code is working fine but what I need to change is that the **save button will be disabled** until
the user **change something in the screen** ,for example type value in text box or change value and in drop down list or check/uncheck the checkBox,how should I do that ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ad</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Server)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.checkBox, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.checkBox)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.checkBox)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedSystemType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSystemType, Model.SystemType)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedSystemType)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need a Client-side code to detect a change in the value.

Here is the jQuery code for that.

```
$('input').change(function () {
   // enable button
}
```

This would be enough, it would check the value for every input field and would trigger only when there is a change in the field. Add more such events that you want.

Checkbox is a type of input element, so it would trigger the same thing. Dropbox (select in HTML) would work with this

```
$('select').change(function () {
   // enable button
}
```

This would check for the select statement change.

Comment: Thanks 1+,but how should I handle the checkBoxs and the drop down list?

Comment: @M.Herbert, I have added that too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunk on how you could achieve this:
http://plnkr.co/egWA78wDnt0VDS4PrxkK

We listen for form change event

```
$("form").change(function() {

});
```

this will work for checkboxes, selects and radio buttons, but for text inputs we need to listen for keyboard events, since change will not trigger before the control loses focus: We listen for keyup

javascript:

```
$(function(){ // document ready function
  $("form").change(function() { // form change (checkboxes, radiobuttons etc)
    $("#submitbtn").show();
  });
  $("input").keyup(function() { // something typed in a textbox
    $("#submitbtn").show();
  });
});
```